# CSS issue with dxDataGrid

Tags: css, devextreme

Having an issue with the css for a dxDataGrid. I have the following example.
[ddxDataGridNotExpanding version 16.1.7](https://jsfiddle.net/asthiss/9sv093z8/)

When expanding the row for "ItemInfoTable" (or any of the lower rows) The grid hides the lower content. Closing the row and expanding it again will correct the issue.

I did the same grid with [version 14.2.7](https://jsfiddle.net/asthiss/8trr5Lvo/) and here it works as intended.

Any CSS guru out there that can find what has been eluding me for days now?

> Update

From my continued investigation it seems to be an issue with how DevExtreme is calculating and setting the height on the div.

```
<div class="dx-datagrid-columns-separator dx-datagrid-columns-separator-transparent"></div>
```

I have open a support case with them so I'll update this when I know more.

Comment: about the code to show your issue , read : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a call to update dimensions on the onContentReady solved the issue.

```
onContentReady: function () {
    $("#attributesetimpl-box").dxDataGrid("updateDimensions");
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sv093z8/2/)